# Mssql doesn't see "strange" characters passed by php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The situation: PHP 5.2.9 => FreeTDS (a CVS version of July, if I remember well) => SQL 2008 R2. PHP is on a CentOS 5.x and Sql server on Windows 2008. Really funny :)

The problem: trying to pass a VARCHAR(2000) to a stored procedure, all goes well, until the string to be passed contains some strange (ok, not so strange) characters like

`‘` , `’` the left/right single quotes

`“` , `”` the left/right double quotes

`&nbsp;` , `&ndash;`

In presence of these characters, the stored procedure executes well, php doesn't report any error, but the field in the db comes out containing an empty string.

Removing these offending characters, the string is correctly parsed.

What to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php

Comment: Does this also happen, when passing any non-latin letters? (ex. ĀǾǔ王)

Comment: @dev-null-dweller with your characters the resulting string is `&#256;&#510;&#468;&#29579;` I'm performing only an utf8_decode on the string before passing it to sql

Comment: If so, try @Phill Pafford solution. My guess was about charset while making connection , but since you pass only iso-8859-1 encoded strings, this should not be issue.

Comment: The utf8_decode, was the first solution that came to my mind,but it's unuseful in this case. I'll proceed removing smart quotes

Comment: non-latin characters are automagically converted in entities even without the utf8_decode function. I think it's a freetds feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Converting Smart Quotes](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php)

Comment: So, should I only take care of smart quotes and en dash?

Comment: No, I'd recommend you look after the complete character encoding.

Comment: I would also add chr(150) or hex \x96 which is not covered in the article.