# Remove special characters using PHP

Tags: php, replace, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace Microsoft-encoded quotes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php)

My string is

```
iPad Applications In Bloom’s Taxonomy and ducause Review: “This Game Sucks”
```

Now I want to replace `" ’ " by " ' " and " “ " by ' " '`

Comment: I think what you're looking for is explained here in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array of character what you want to remove and use str_replace to replace with something else.

```
ex: $remove = array(',','"',"'",'by','and son on..');
$str = iPad Applications In Bloom’s Taxonomy and ducause Review: “This Game Sucks”;
$return = str_replace($remove,' ',$str);
```

thanks..

Comment: But when i replace my string with variable name it does not work like this : str_replace(array('’', '“',"”"), array("'", '"','"'), $variableName);

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_replace(array('’', '“', '”'), array("'", '"', '"'), 'iPad Applications In Bloom’s Taxonomy and ducause Review: “This Game Sucks”');
```

[See the results of execution on ideone](http://ideone.com/DnCoG)

Comment: But when i replace my string with variable name it does not work like this : str_replace(array('’', '“',"”"), array("'", '"','"'), $variableName);

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao: it does work for me. Show the exact code that doesn't work

Comment: Here is code :  echo str_replace(array('’', '“','”'), array("'", '"','"'), $featuredTitle);

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao: and it works fine with the string you've given

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "iPad Applications In Bloom’s Taxonomy and ducause Review: “This Game Sucks”"
$search = array("’", "“");
$replace = array("'", '"');
$new_text = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
```

Comment: But when i replace my string with variable name it does not work like this : str_replace(array('’', '“',"”"), array("'", '"','"'), $variableName);

Comment: It definitely works unless those characters look similar but are actually different.

check character codes of each letter in your string with `chr()` command in php and use like this `$search = array(chr(xxx), chr(xxx));`

Answer (score 0):

Try [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

Comment: But when i replace my string with variable name it does not work like this : str_replace(array('’', '“',"”"), array("'", '"','"'), $variableName);

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao - Then show us your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) :

```
 $string = str_replace(array("’",  "“"), array("'", '"'), $string);
```

Comment: But when i replace my string with variable name it does not work like this : str_replace(array('’', '“',"”"), array("'", '"','"'), $variableName);