# Proper Encoding/PHP String Manipulation

Tags: php, string, encoding

So I've just created a simple form for coworkers to submit stories/articles to, and I'm having it send it to me as an email with the mail() function.

Now, most of my coworkers are writing in Word, and then copy/pasting to the submission form.

Sometimes, they're using bullets and apostrophes inside their text, and this is throwing odd symbols.

Now, I'm not too familiar with encoding (I know basics, like UTF-8 has several different bits depending on the language in question)

My question is - how do I encode the input properly so that either these symbols get replaced by the proper ones (in the case of bullets, I may have to write a regex that adds `<li>` and `</li>` tags), but what about apostrophes?

Is there an accepted method for how to do this? I can provide the code if you'd like, but it's all very simple form submission via POST and using the mail() function.

Comment: Perhaps the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function can help. Are you sending plain-text email or HTML email?

Comment: Googling for "php convert smart quotes" also turned up [this](http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace Microsoft-encoded quotes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php)

Comment: Also interested in the bullets issue too, though I don't see a way that can be fixed.

Comment: You should be able to extend the smart-quotes technique to cover bullets -- `chr(149)`, according to [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Data-Type-Functions/UsingtheChrFunctionandConstantstoEnterSpecialCharactersinaString.htm) -- I would convert them into asterisks for plain text, or `&bull;` for html.

Comment: Wouldn't I just want to convert them into <li> tags, and then do a regex looking for the next newline after the <li> and insert a </li> there?

Comment: That depends on whether you're composing an HTML email or not.

Comment: Hrm, that method did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up the input with `htmlspecialchars`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php