# Replace each ’ with ' in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have following `textarea` field in `question form` where user can post their questions:

```
<tr>
    <th><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('question'); ?>: </label></th>
    <td><textarea  value="" id="ques_desc" name="ques_desc"
        class="validate[required] text-input" > </textarea> </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is when user copies and paste question from world or excel,
then symbol `'` becomes `’` and get stored in the database in the same format.

Example:

```
Check men's and women's rest rooms
```

becomes

```
Check men’s and women’s rest rooms
```

And when user searches for `Check men's` in the search field then
`Check men’s` does not appear in the search result.

I tried str_replace function with `’` and `'` , it does not worked.
example:

```
$ques_desc = str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc);
```

does not replace `’` to `'`.

What might be the way to replace each `’` with `'` ?

**EDIT:**

When I do this on view page:

```
<?php 
$ques_desc1 = "Check men’s and women’s rest rooms "; 
$ques_desc = str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc1); 
echo $ques_desc; 
?>
```

It displays:

```
Check men's and women's rest rooms
```

It worked!

When I do this on controller:

```
$ques_desc1 = $this->input->post('ques_desc');
$ques_desc = str_replace(" ",".",$ques_desc1);
```

It displays:
`Take O’pening Stock Count` to `Take.O’pening.Stock.Count`

it also worked!

But when I do this:

```
$ques_desc1 = $this->input->post('ques_desc');
$ques_desc = str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc1);
```

It does not work. Nothing changes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better solution to fix your search engine? For example, if your database ever needed to store the word `café` and people wanted to search with `cafe`, then maybe you could change the `é` to `e`, but then you'd start mangling non-English text.

Comment: I expect it to be unicode char which just looks like a quote. You need to know which char it is actually. Would be nice if you could post a hexdump of your data. Have coded a [hexdump](https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump) package for PHP once. Maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str_replace` like this

```
echo str_replace("’","'","Check men’s and women’s rest rooms");
```

## Output

```
Check men's and women's rest rooms
```

[Code Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/n02jFT)

Comment: So long as there is no Unicode where `0x27` is part of a multi-byte character.

Comment: As I already said, I tried str_replace before posting to database it does not work at all.
$ques_desc = str_replace("'","’",$ques_desc);
does not replaces ’ to '.

Comment: @alex: So long as it's UTF-8, that can't happen. No bytes with high bits clear will be part of a multibyte sequence.

Comment: @icktoofay I just figured that out when trying to make an example. :)

Comment: Yeah. It works on viewpage. When I do this:
`<?php 
$ques_desc1 = "Check men’s and women’s rest rooms "; 
$ques_desc = str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc1); 
echo $ques_desc; 
?>`
It displays:
`Check men's and women's rest rooms`

But, when data goes to controller:
`$ques_desc1 = $this->input->post('ques_desc');
$ques_desc = str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc1);`
Here,
`str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc1)` does not work. But `str_replace(" ",".",$ques_desc1)` works perfectly.

Comment: @Venonj - please include working/not working example in your question (edit it) above. It's easier to read then.

Comment: I got the solution. Check it to my answer please.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution of my own problem.

I tried this:

```
$ques_desc1 = $this->input->post('ques_desc');
$ques_desc = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ques_desc1);
```

Here, `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ques_desc1)` replaces Microsoft Word version of single  and double quotations marks `“ ” ‘ ’` with  regular quotes `'` and `"`.

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: +1 for finding your own solution, and I also get the solution for my own reference...:P

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in `str_replace` syntax. you should put `’` as first parameter and `'` as second so change this:

```
$ques_desc = str_replace("'","’",$ques_desc);
```

to :

```
$ques_desc = str_replace("’","'",$ques_desc);
```

Comment: I got the solution. Check it to my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having trouble with Microsoft Word's smart quotes. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262210/288357) for a couple of tips for handling that.

I did a quick and dirty test and [this particular method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262210/288357) worked:

```php
$quotes = array(
    "\xC2\xAB"     => '"', // « (U+00AB) in UTF-8
    "\xC2\xBB"     => '"', // » (U+00BB) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x98" => "'", // ‘ (U+2018) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x99" => "'", // ’ (U+2019) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x9A" => "'", // ‚ (U+201A) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x9B" => "'", // ‛ (U+201B) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x9C" => '"', // “ (U+201C) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x9D" => '"', // ” (U+201D) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x9E" => '"', // „ (U+201E) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\x9F" => '"', // ‟ (U+201F) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\xB9" => "'", // ‹ (U+2039) in UTF-8
    "\xE2\x80\xBA" => "'", // › (U+203A) in UTF-8
);
$str = strtr($str, $quotes);
```

Comment: I have to agree with icktoofay in the comments, though, that besides this it would also be a good idea to retool your search engine so that it can match more loosely.

Comment: I got the solution. Check it to my answer please.