# Regex not accepting apostrophe and quotes when copied from MS Word

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, unicode, ms-word

I was doing validation which accepts some special characters, dashes, quotes, apostrophe etc.

here is the code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cityvalidation", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\'\U+2019]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
}, "You Have Typed Unallowed Charactors");
```

it is working fine unless if somebody copy quotes or apostrophe from MS Word, then the validation gives else error "You Have Typed Unallowed Charactors" as it does not accept quotes  and apostrophe from MS Word.

Please suggest if there is any unicode or character for MS Word quotes and apostrophe that can also bee added in the Validation Regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, after tons of search and heavy coded solutions which were difficult for me to understand, I tried one silly solution, I just typed the quotes and apostrophe in MS word and then copied from Word and added in my RegEx Code. below is the latest one:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cityvalidation", function (value, element) {
    //return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\s\)\(]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\'\‘\’\”\“]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
}, "You Have Typed Unallowed Charactors");
```

As of now its not giving any issue, I tested in multiple browsers too and its working Great!

Hope this works for everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

MS Word uses a different encoding so you need to use the Regex for them.

single quotes and apostrophe

```
\u2018\u2019\u201A
```

double quotes

```
\u201C\u201D\u201E
```

How to use them from here: https://prcode.blog/2015/10/17/ms-word-special-characters-regex/