# echoing text from mysql with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm trying to echo some text that I put into mysql that contains apostrophes. However whenever I try to echo the text out the apostrophes are replaced with boxes.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM rules";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row =  $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<article class="content grid_10 push_1">';

    echo '<h1>';
    echo $row['title'];
    echo '</h1>';

    echo '<section>';

    echo nl2br(stripslashes($row['post']));

    echo '</section>';
    echo '</article>';

}?>
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue.

Comment: What's your page encoding? Try to set up UTF-8.

Comment: You might have an encodIng issue. There is a meta tag for the head to define the encodIng type.

Comment: I have the meta tag with the encoding <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: What about DB encoding for your `rules` table ?

Comment: try using `urlencode()` that should solve your problem

Comment: The Encoding for the text is set to default latin1_swedish_ci

I'll try urlencode to see if that works

Comment: apostrophes? do you mean diacritical marks such as é and è ?

Comment: Try to change to utf8_general_ci in DB.

Comment: cant see what you expect urlencode to do here its for url's after all

Comment: I just figured it out. I was using ` instead of '. However I still don't want ` outputting as boxes. Is there a fix for this

Comment: are  they real backticks of ms curly quotes?

Comment: @user3687047 it's probably also not a `\`` , but some fancy Microsoft Word alternative. The normal `\`` should not be sensitive for the charset, IMHO

Comment: assuming we are correct, i would fix them befor they go in to the db: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php?lq=1

Comment: mysqli_set_charset() http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this (encoding with utf-8):

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM rules";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row =  $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<article class="content grid_10 push_1">';

    echo '<h1>';
    echo utf8_encode($row['title']);
    echo '</h1>';

    echo '<section>';

    echo nl2br(stripslashes(utf8_encode($row['post'])));

    echo '</section>';
    echo '</article>';

}?>
```