# Troubles replacing MS "smart" quotes php

Tags: php, str-replace

I am attempting to use the solution found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php) to remove Microsoft smart quotes from a string before I export the data to CSV file. However, it doesn't seem to be working for me.

This is my code:

```
$Wp_NewsText = str_replace(
    array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151)),
    array("'", "'", "\"", "\"", "-"),
    $Wp_NewsText
);
```

But for some reason the download still contains the smart quotes. I thought it might be that, because a CSV needs double quotes as a delimiter, it was somehow reverting the quotes back to smart quotes, so I tried this:

```
$Wp_NewsText = str_replace(
    array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151)),
    array("&apos;", "&apos;", "&quot;", "&quot;", "&dash;"),
    $Wp_NewsText
);
```

But that didn't solve the problem. So I tried copy-pasting the *actual* characters in to the array:

```
$Wp_NewsText = str_replace(
    array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151), "“", "”"),
    array("&apos;", "&apos;", "&quot;", "&quot;", "&dash;", "&quot;", "&quot;"),
    $Wp_NewsText
);
```

But alas, still no luck. Finally I've tried JSON encoding/decoding everything because apparently that's faster, but I was hoping it might have some other useful side-effect of making the code work.

```
$Wp_NewsText = json_decode(
    str_replace(
        array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151), "“", "”"),
        array("&apos;", "&apos;", "&quot;", "&quot;", "&dash;", "&quot;", "&quot;"),
        json_encode($Wp_NewsText)
    )
);
```

Nope.

The actual string I'm attempting to replace these characters in is as follows:

> “There is significant intellectual property to be gleaned from these advanced automotive technology development programs; not least being the pursuit of silent drivetrains, where we’re focusing significant effort,” Setter said.

**EDIT:** If it matters, all of my code and text is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I tested your 3rd example with the additional `"“", "”"` with my PHP 7.1.1 interpreter and it actually does what you want, it replaces the quotes with `&quot;` like expected!?

Comment: Here the result `&quot;There is significant intellectual property to be gleaned from these advanced automotive technology development programs; not least being the pursuit of silent drivetrains, where we’re focusing significant effort,&quot; Setter said.`.

Comment: Interesting... neither my code, nor http://phpfiddle.org/, worked for me.

Comment: you're right phpfiddle.org seems not to work, but this is for me: https://ideone.com/8jPig4 seems to be an encoding problem if your local PHP version isnt working either, but the code seems to be working as you can see.