# PHP Load HTML Converting quotes (") to special characters

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

I have an input where users can enter their html which is later displayed as part of the body. To make sure user entered html is properly closed, I am using this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($body);
$dom->removeChild($dom->doctype);
$body = $dom->saveHTML();

$body = str_replace('<html><body>', '', $body);
$body = str_replace('</body></html>', '', $body);
$body = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $body)));
```

Now, if the user entered content contains double quotes (“) or single quotes, this is converting it into something like `&acirc;&#128;&#156;` which is being displayed as `â€œ` in the html. How do I make sure special characters like quotes are displayed properly?

**EDIT:**
Here's a sample of text which is being pasted:

```
It is called a “buddy list,” “friend list” or “contact list." Users are typically alerted when someone on their list is online.
```

which is being converting into:

```
It is called a â€œbuddy list,â€ â€œfriend listâ€ or â€œcontact list." Users are typically alerted when someone on their list is online.
```

Comment: Those look like smart quotes. You could try replacing them - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$str1 = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);

$str = html_entity_decode($str1);
?>
```