# html_entity_decode not working for some html entities like &#132;

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode, htmldecode

I have the following code:

```
echo html_entity_decode("&#132;", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Result is `&#132;` but expected result is `„`.

I also tried `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8`, but it's still the same.

Why isn't `html_entity_decode` working in this case?

Comment: That is a special character, not html entity. This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php

Answer (score -1):

This is a special char, not html entity, so I thin this would be the right way.

```
<?php
    $str = "&#132;";
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

    ?>
```

Comment: I just ran that code. It output `&#132;` when the desired output is `„`